# What is the rationale of Lithuania allowing a diplomatic mission under the name of Taiwan, thus deteriorating the diplomatic relation with China?

Tags: china, international-relations, taiwan, lithuania

[This article](https://www.smh.com.au/world/europe/china-hits-out-at-lithuania-after-it-allows-a-de-facto-taiwan-embassy-20210811-p58hod.html) provides some insight into the recent diplomatic tensions between Lithuania and China:

> Taiwan announced the new mission last month, saying it would be called
> the Taiwanese Representative Office in Lithuania, the first time the
> island’s name has been used for one of its offices in Europe, as
> normally only “Taipei” is used.
>
> Taiwan took part in the Tokyo 2020 Olympics under the name of “Chinese
> Taipei”.
>
> Lithuania’s permission for the office to open under the name of Taiwan
> was done “in disregard of China’s repeated representations and
> articulation of potential consequences”, and severely undermines
> China’s sovereignty, the Chinese Foreign Ministry said on Tuesday
> AEST.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_diplomatic_missions_of_Taiwan) there are several dozens of countries that have more or less official relations with Taiwan/Republic of China, but all but the representative office in Somaliland took care to avoid "Taiwan" in their official names.

I am wondering why Lithuania broke this rule especially that European Commission seems to acknowledge that Taiwan is not a sovereign state ([example below](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taiwan%E2%80%93European_Union_relations#History)):

> the EU Commission referred Taiwan as a "separate customs territory,
> but **not as a sovereign state**", highlighting the role of Taiwan as
> autonomous economic entity for the purposes of the establishment of
> relations with the European Union.[4]

Comment: What a poor question. Nobody but Lithuania's government can answer it definitively, therefore the only possible answers it can get will be opinionated guesses.

Comment: @IanKemp If Politics.SE would be only about definitive answers, half of the current opened questions would get closed. Btw - there are no definitive answers in programming, so how would can we expect to have them in politics?

Comment: In addition to what @user26742873 mentioned, China is, in some sense of the word, 'cut off' from the open ocean by chains of islands stretching from South Korea through Japan, Taiwan, the Phillipines and Indonesia/Malasia/Singapore; assuming them all to be sovereign states with a common defence agreement, the straits between the islands could be closed off very effectively which China definitely wants to avoid.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that most actions that China might take a country it can't take against Lithuania because China's trade relations are with the EU not with Lithuania directly.

Comment: @JackAidley totally, that's what I meant by *not obviously all that exposed to China's displeasure*

Comment: @user253751 I am not aware that the Republic of China (do not confuse with PRC) ever claimed they are a separate country from China.

Comment: @VladimirF that's also for political reasons.

Comment: @user253751 Sure, but if they do not claim it themselves, why others should?

Comment: @ValidmirF It depends on why they didn't make that claim.  Lithuania isn't facing pressure from America.  And the amount of pressure Lithuania faces from China is different than the amount of pressure Taiwan faces from China.

Comment: Lithuania and Taiwan have something pretty obvious in common ... a powerful neighbour with a tendency to want to annex them...

Comment: @user_1818839 What does Russia have to do with this?

Comment: @Readin Currently : not a lot. Historically : gave Lithuania some experience of involuntary rule imposed from outside, and perhaps some sympathy for a country facing a similar situation.

Comment: @user_1818839 Ok. Sorry I misunderstood.  I thought you were disagreeing with something said earlier rather than just introducing new information.

Comment: @VladimirF In my memory they always claim so. In international area where PRC and RoC need to stand together, they all call themselves simply 'China' to rid of embarrassment. RoC has planned to take control of mainland China again, like what they have did before WWII, but so many years later PRC has changed too much.

Comment: @user26742873 They both claim to be the only legitimate government of China. Of the only China. There is only one China, but with two governments each ruling a part of the country and each calling the other illegitimate. But the legitimacy is less important here. The important bit is that they both claim to be the government of the single China. Not  an independent separate country of Taiwan. So perhaps we actually agree with each other? Did I just not express myself clear enough?

Comment: @VladimirF Thanks for your reply, I misunderstood your previous comment.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Look for the Lithuanian PM's name, Google for that - *Ingrida Šimonytė declaration taiwan* and Taiwan and you [find](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-lithuania-china-idUSKBN27P1PQ).

> The Lithuanian coalition agreement, signed by leaders of the Homeland Union, Liberal Movement and Freedom parties, which together won 74 seats in the 141-seat parliament on Oct. 25, binds the new government to carry out a “values-based foreign policy”.
>
> “We will actively oppose any violation of human rights and democratic freedoms, and will defend those fighting for freedom around the world, from Belarus to Taiwan,” they said.

I suppose Lithuania's historical fondness for all things Communist may have something to do with it.  That, and they are not obviously all that exposed to China's displeasure, so... why not?

I think what is happening, compared to "the dozens of other countries" before, is that a number of countries are getting fed up with Xi's China and acting in ways that they would not have 10 years ago.

It's really rather tragic - in the past most countries, maybe aside from the US, could see China taking its rightful (by size and economic weight) place in the sun and would have seen no reason to oppose it in the same way as they did the USSR.  On the other hand, China's CCP thrives on nationalism, and internal and external coercion, so is over-reaching too early.

It didn't have to be Cold War 2.  China isn't really Communist anymore in nature and isn't inherently an *internationalist* nuisance, "just" a dictatorship.  Looks like relations are heading that way however.

#### Edit:  re "the rambling".

First the question asks why Lithuania is departing from hitherto common practice (see also Fizz's answer for internal political reasons).  Second, while that's my take on it, I didn't invent it:

[China’s ‘wolf warrior’ diplomacy is anything but effective](https://responsiblestatecraft.org/2021/06/23/chinas-wolf-warrior-diplomacy-is-anything-but-effective/)

> Chinese foreign policy has become more assertive and heavy-handed in the last decade, and as a result it has alienated some of its neighbors and fueled greater wariness of Beijing’s intentions in the region. As China has become wealthier and more powerful, the Chinese government has shown greater willingness to throw its weight around even at the cost of antagonizing and insulting other governments.

[China Has an Image Problem—but Knows How to Fix It](https://foreignpolicy.com/2021/04/06/china-image-problem-wolf-warrior-international/)

> It isn’t just the United States. Around the world, unfavorable views of China have reached unprecedented heights in the last year, with the percentage of individuals having  in Chinese leadership to “do the right thing” in world affairs rising by more than 15 percent across countries like Australia, Germany, Italy, the Netherlands, and the United Kingdom. The reaction among the Italian public is particularly noteworthy, given the China has offered the country during the COVID-19 pandemic.

[Too soon, too loud: Chinese foreign policy advisers tell ‘Wolf Warrior’ diplomats to tone it down](https://www.scmp.com/news/china/diplomacy/article/3084274/too-soon-too-loud-chinese-foreign-policy-advisers-tell-wolf)

> The speech by Shi, who has been an adviser to the State Council, China’s cabinet, since 2011, was posted on an official university social media account on Monday.  He also said China should change course “as soon as possible” and instead take a more nuanced approach to the rising anti-China sentiment among policymakers in Washington.
> “When both the official and non-official media are all adopting an aggressive tone when reporting about the US, it’s not conducive to [turning] public opinion,” he said, suggesting Beijing should direct some of its official media to take a more conciliatory tone.
>
> Shi also called for a halt to the debate about the origin of the virus “because this is only exacerbating the blame game between China and the US”, saying that it would take time to find an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the quote, but then rest of the answer kind of rambles without getting to a point. Would be better quote only and even better with some coherent interpretation of the quote.

Comment: I actually quite enjoy the rambling. Seems to give an interesting perspective.

Comment: Dictatorships _are_ inherently international nuisances.

Comment: @Vikki *internationalist*, not *international*. see en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proletarian_internationalism.  I believe there was a SE.Po question about Lenin vs Stalin on the subject of **internationalizing** the revolution or not in in the last 3-4 months.  Briefly put, the initial position of Communism was supposedly to try to export itself by all means necessary.  Possibly to defend itself, possibly offensively.  Doesn't really matter the reason.

Comment: Lithuania was under Russian control since half a century before USA was even founded. What USSR specifically has to do with Taiwan situation?

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov  Great of you to ask, buddy.  Let's look at [Soviet occupation of the Baltic states (1940) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soviet_occupation_of_the_Baltic_states_(1940))  : *After the Soviet invasion of Poland on 17 September 1939, in accordance with the Molotov–Ribbentrop Pact the Soviet forces were given freedom over Latvia, Lithuania and Estonia, an important aspect of the agreement to the Soviet government as they were afraid of Germany using the three states as a corridor to get close to Leningrad.*  At at guess, that's why the Lithuanians dislike Communists.

Comment: Given that Lithuania was invaded in 1940 and that there is a Lithuanian language, my guess is that Lithuania did not consider itself part of Russia and that they did not take kindly to occupation.  And that's before the general resentment many forcibly-inducted Warsaw Pact nations had against Communist rule.  Do you also need information about the Molotov-Ribbentrop Pact?

Comment: "Lithuania's historical fondness for all things Communist" I guess this is an attempt at sarcasm?!

Answer (score 14):

Since 2020 Lithuania has been governed by a fairly right-wing government. They have sometimes [disagreed](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-58163073), at least to some degree, with the EU on other stuff, e.g. in in mid 2021 on the building of a fence with Belarus ("a spokesman for the EU said the bloc "does not finance fences or barriers". So far, the EU has offered help in the form of border guards and supplies instead.")

Now [about Taiwan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithuania%E2%80%93Taiwan_relations); this seems to be mainly due to the fact that the [Freedom Party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_Party_(Lithuania)) is a (minority) partner in the government coalition (since 2020). For whatever reason, the Freedom Party has this extremely pro-Taiwan position in their platform, demanding "full recognition of the independence of Taiwan". So it was almost certainly due to their presence in the coalition that Taiwan got the level of recognition  that caused China to  react.

> Lithuania's Freedom Party has a clause supporting full recognition of the independence of Taiwan (ROC), and in the 2020 Lithuanian parliamentary election, parties sympathetic to Taiwan such as the Homeland Union and Freedom Party entered government and formed a coalition. In 2021, the Lithuania-Taiwan Forum was established by over 50 Lithuanian political figures, and it was announced that Lithuania would open a trade office in Taiwan amidst growing discontent with China's "17 + 1" program.

As far as Europe-wide trend, the Lithuanian Freedom Party is probably not alone in this, as another ALDE member, Germany's FDP [has also](https://www.taipeitimes.com/News/taiwan/archives/2021/05/19/2003757661) recently changed position on Taiwan, albeit only as far as supporting self-determination.

Now going back a bit farther in time... around 2019 [there was](https://chinaobservers.eu/a-diplomatic-incident-in-lithuania-troubles-its-relationship-with-china/) a wave of solidarity protests with Hong Kong in the Baltic states. China's flag in the region has been sinking since around that time. On this emotional level, China is seen in the Baltics as an oppressor analogue of the [former] Soviet Union. It probably didn't hurt (the anti-PRC side) that they paid homage to the Baltics' way/form of protesting--I'm referring to the "human chain":

> In 1989 approximately two million people joined their hands to form a human chain spanning almost 700 km and connecting the three republican capitals to mark the 50th anniversary of the infamous Molotov–Ribbentrop Pact and protest their subsequent annexation by the Soviet Union. [...]
>
> The eventful day took a rather unexpected turn when several hundreds of Lithuanians that joined hands in solidarity with the protesters in Hong Kong were confronted by a small but vocal group of pro-Beijing counter-demonstrators in downtown Vilnius. At around the same time in Hong Kong, an estimated 210,000 people formed their own
> ‘Hong Kong Way’ spanning some 60 km as part of the ongoing Anti-Extradition Law protests in the city. The alleged author of the idea, an anonymous Tallinn-based Hong Kong startup entrepreneur, explicitly named the Baltic Way as an inspiration. [...]
>
> The solidarity event was co-organized by Lithuania’s active and vocal Tibet support group, and there were as many Tibetan “snow lion” flags as the Hongkongese ones among the demonstrators in Vilnius. [...]
>
> It needs to be noted that this was not the first time that the 1989 events in the Baltic republics were linked with China. Back in 2004, an approximately 2 million-strong and 500 km-long pro-independence [228 Hand-in-Hand rally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/228_Hand-in-Hand_rally) in Taiwan was also inspired by the prior Baltics example.

The Lithuanian Freedom Party was founded in mid-2019, it seems, so the fact that their platform capitalized/embodied [on] this kind of anti-PRC sentiment probably isn't a coincidence.

Comment: This answer seems very opinionated, and also contains factual errors. Fences can be found for example along the the Spain-Morocco border and the Norway (not in EU, but in Schengen)-Russia. The Finnish-Russian border has an exclusion zone which is forbidden to enter. 

Furthermore Lithuania is the second most EU-positive country in the EU.

Comment: If you must mention the fence (which is barely relevant), you should mention the context: it is not built against the Belorussians (who "genuinely flee like during the Cold War"): they have never been a significant problem. It is specifically against the African and Middle Eastern migrants being ferried by Lukashenko just to annoy the neighbours.

Comment: @Zeus - not only annoy. Blackmail EU to cancel the sanctions, as expressly said Lukashenko. Belorussia actively promotes trip to "visitors" as entry to EU and after arrival, chaperones them to Lithuania's border.

Comment: @Zeus the Hungarian fence was also not built against fleeing Bulgarians.

Comment: You misstate a quote you provide.  The quote says, "Lithuania's Freedom Party has a clause supporting full recognition of the independence of Taiwan" but in  your own words you say, "basically demanding full independence".  Based on the the quote, the Freedom Party isn't demanding Taiwan be independent because the Freedom Party knows Taiwan is already independent.  The Freedom Party is demanding recognition of that fact.  It's a subtle difference but the diplomacy surrounding Taiwan is full of such subtleties and they are important.

Comment: @Fizz The Economist has an article specifically about that this week.  To the point where Western governments have managed to pressure Iraq to disallow its citizen to board flights to Belarus where Lukashenko was inviting them to cross over to annoy the EU: *In 2020 just 74 people crossed from Belarus to Lithuania illegally. This year more than 4,000 people have tried. All this was overseen by Alexander Lukashenko, the Belarusian president, whose government had encouraged the arrivals. “We will not hold anyone back,” said Mr Lukashenko. “They are headed to enlightened, warm, cosy Europe.”*

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: yeah, well, the EU got too used to dictators [enforcing](https://apnews.com/article/europe-middle-east-health-coronavirus-pandemic-migration-cf9ea006cc5f43792c79f62bd4bfef11) its immigration policy (in Africa and elsewhere.) Frankly, I'd be curious to know if, in comparison to Turkey [and some African gov'ts], if Lukashenko had signed any piece of paper promising not to let the migrants through. Because otherwise he's probably not breaking any international norms other than those the EU imagines should exist.

Comment: And probably a better link would have been https://www.tni.org/en/outsourcingoppression than the bland AP reporting on high-level talks.

Comment: Outsourcing immigration to dictatorships isn't *necessarily* unethical.  If say you manage to get Algerian or Moroccan authorities - not exactly paragons of good civil stewardship - to block the open boarding of migrant smuggling boats in their ports, you are likely to end up picking less dead bodies out of the Mediterranean waters later on.  So things are sometimes more complex than they can appear.

Comment: @Fizz Please don't move the goalposts. It started with 'Where does Lukashenko find all these Afghans etc. to "ferry"?' You got the answer, if it's not enough, [here](https://www.reuters.com/world/how-belarus-became-gateway-eu-middle-east-migrants-2021-11-09/) [you](https://www.aa.com.tr/en/middle-east/iraq-halts-working-permit-of-belarus-consulate-in-baghdad/2419636) [have](https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/how-minsk-became-mecca-migrants-travelling-tourists-2021-11-15/) [more](https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/hundreds-migrants-remain-poland-belarus-border-temperatures-drop-2021-11-09/)

Comment: You first suggested, that the fence is to prevent Belorussians to flee the dictatorship and that you don't believe in this flood of Middle East migrants. When proofs were shown, you changed to "but inviting them and allowing to move west is legal".

Comment: @TadeuszKopec: well, hindsight is 20/20. I concede that I was too skeptical of the claims Lukashenka purposefully imported migrants from the middle east to re-export them to the West (I mean even Turkey didn't do that--it had them already) until I read some of the investigative pieces on this in the later months on the Iraqi flights etc. https://www.bbc.com/news/world-58952867 https://www.nytimes.com/2021/11/13/world/middleeast/belarus-migrants-iraq-kurds.html (But all the stories you've linked to me were from Nov. The evidence wasn't so overwhelming in August when the above discussion hapened